# take different powers of a vector and save in txtfile

Tags: python, numpy, save

I am trying to take different powers of a vector `c` and then save each of these new vectors in a single textfile, where every column is a vector.
For example, the array `c` has elements:

```
0.836205
0.394242
0.705833
0.361308
0.0597318
-0.0345422
0.864248
0.811093
0.409232
0.150628
0.706122
0.854921
```

I would like to elevate `c` to the powers `q=np.arange(-1,5.5,0.5)` and save `c^q` for all `q` in a txtfile where each column is a `c^q`.
My output txtfile should be composed of 13 columns (one column for each `q`). I guess I should use `np.power(c,q)` function but I can't figure out which loop I have to use to save all vectors for all `q's`

For now what I have done is to solve it very mechanically and very inefficiently:

```
for i in range(len(c)):                                                      
 c_2=np.power(c,2) 
 c2.append(c_2)
```

for every value of q (here for example I did it for `q=2`).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I have done it very mechanically and very inefficiently:

`for i in range(len(c)):
    c_2=np.power(c,2)
    c2.append(c_2)
`

for every value of `q` (here for example I did it for `q=2`)

Comment: update your question to show the code you have. Comments don't allow for formatting. Please also provide a **verifiable** example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you loop is going through the array c and taking the square of every element:

```
for i in range(len(c)):
    c_2=np.power(c,2) 
    c2.append(c_2)
```

But numpy offers the possibility to do that automatically:

```
c = np.array([1,2,3])
c2 = np.power(c, 2)
# returns "array([1, 4, 9], dtype=int32)"
```

so you can save the effort to do it for each element. The next logical step is to do the power for each element in your `q`. So you could do a loop over the `q` and take the power of `c` and append it:

```
q = [2,3,4]
res = []
for i in q:
    res.append(np.power(c, i))
res = np.array(res)
# afterwards res is just 
# array([[ 1,  4,  9],
#        [ 1,  8, 27],
#        [ 1, 16, 81]], dtype=int32)
```

that's not what you wanted, you wanted it to be that the columns are the vectores. So have a look at [`np.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html).

Actually there is also another way doing it without a loop just by clever broadcasting:

```
res = c[:, None] ** q[None, :]
```

and then afterwards you can save your file for example with [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html). I'll leave you to figure out which arguments must be set in order to get the saved file you wanted.